# I converted an image to numpy array but when I try to reconvert to image using PIL it shows Maximum Supported Dimension error

Tags: python, pandas, image

I am trying to use PCA on my images dataset. I have converted the images to a 1-D array and saved as a dataframe. I have then applied the PCA library from scikit and have got a resulting dataframe. But now when I use PIL to reconvert the array to an image it is showing me an error - "Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels"

The size of the original image is 250*300.

The code is as follows:

```
faces = pd.DataFrame([])
for path in iglob('*/*.jpg'):
 img=imread(path)
 face = pd.Series(img.flatten(),name=path)    #Image converted to numpy Series
 faces = faces.append(face).                  #Numpy series now added to dataframe

 
faces_pca = PCA(n_components= 0.8).          #Computing Eigenvectors for PCA to get 80% variance
faces_pca.fit(faces)


components = faces_pca.transform(faces)
projected = faces_pca.inverse_transform(components) #Dataframe with updated values for image 

print(projected)

img = Image.fromarray(projected[0], 'RGB')   #Extracting one series from dataframe to convert to image
img.save('image_1_pca.jpeg')
img.show()
```

Comment: I don't know what libraries you are using for PCA because you have unhelpfully removed the `import` statements, but it looks as though your array `projected[0]` is the wrong shape, so you probably need to use `img= Image.fromarray(projected[0].rehsape((HEIGHT,WIDTH))...`